# Divide rows of table

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a little knowledge about `HTML` and `CSS` and `bootstrap`. And i tried to design a table similar this picture which i attached.

But i had a problem that i didn't know how to design same as this picture.

[image]

This is my demo code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khanhpn/DTcHh/15954/)

Hope everybody can help me ? Thank you very much.

**Edit:**

I tried to Graham's solution, but it didn't same as my picture.
[image]

[update solutions](https://jsfiddle.net/khanhpn/DTcHh/15968/)

Comment: Your image link is broken please check.

Comment: Thank you, i checked, can you refresh your browser ? Please.

Comment: @KhanhPham still image link broken.

Comment: Sorry. I updated image. Can you check it again? Thank you very much.

Comment: you are using table , for better control use, div layout instead for table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the DEMO, Rest styles you can implement am sure :), if stuck somewhere do let me know.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>

        .bg-info {
            background-color: #5EC2F7 !important;
        }
        .borderTop {
            border-top: 2px solid black;
        }
        .borderBottom {
            border-bottom: 2px solid black;
        }
        .borderLeft {
            border-left: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
  <div class="container">
        
        <div class="row bg-info ">
            <div class="col-xs-6 borderTop borderLeft">風速</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 borderTop  borderLeft ">0.9 m/s</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 borderTop borderLeft">最大瞬間風速</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 borderTop borderLeft">1.7 m/s</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 borderLeft">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 borderTop borderLeft col-xs-offset-6 ">風向</div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 borderTop borderLeft">NE</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 borderLeft">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 borderTop  borderLeft col-xs-offset-6 ">起時</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 borderTop borderLeft">13:23</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 borderTop borderBottom borderLeft">5</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 borderTop borderBottom borderLeft">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's so wonderful. Thank you very much. This is solution what i expect.
One again, thank you very much.

Comment: Glad, I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

job done, this is what you want. try this

```
        <tr>
          <td><span class="pull-right">風向</span></td>
          <td>NE</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it don't same as my picture.

Comment: what is the problem with it.I have check it with your fiddle

Comment: I update my question, please check it again. Thank you.

Comment: do you want the background color for the space, that is what you expect

Comment: Yes, and the border is very thick. 
This is picture what i expect.

http://i1161.photobucket.com/albums/q514/baran19901990/test1_zpsjc4k08jf.png?t=1452667347

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I've just tried your solution, but it's not same as my picture.

I think that @Anil Panwar's answer is the best.